# Big Query Input Errors

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I resolve the following error on Big Query:

**Expected end of input but got "(" at [3:13]**

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
usertype
CONCAT  (start_station_name," to ", end_station_name) AS route,
COUNT(*) as num_trips,
ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60), 2) AS duration
```

FROM
`bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips'
GROUP BY
start.start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10

Comment: Missing comma after usertype

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much. Can't believe I missed that.